# How to monitor network performance for each application in FreeBSD / PC-BSD?

Tags: networking, freebsd

I'm using a PC-BSD workstation, and I would like to know if there is a way to monitor which app / process is using the network.

I use a Mac OS X (Mavericks) laptop, and the "Network" tab in the "Activity Monitor" allows to see which process is sending / receiving data to / from the network. But I don't see (or haven't found) anything like that in FreeBSD. Since Mac OS X is similar to FreeBSD under the hood, is there any graphical app (similar to System Monitor) or command-line utility (similar to `top`) to monitor network activity for each process?

Answer (score 1):

You could give it a try at jnettop: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnettop/ - http://www.freshports.org/net-mgmt/jnettop/ , but process id information should be missing.

With `iftop` you could have a detailed bandwidth report (`iftop -i re0 -N -P`), but you will not see(again) the process id of a specific network traffic. You´ll have to deduce what traffic is associated with what software.

There is a tool called `nethogs` on Linux, but since it heavly depends on `/proc` could not be trivial to port it to FreeBSD - http://marc.info/?l=freebsd-questions&m=127092700612560&w=2

Answer (score 1):

Almost any regular Unix networking tool you know of is available on FreeBSD including nmap, ntop, and a multitude of others, none of which I can think of right now.